# Why won’t the ground take my seed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m playing a bit of hardcore and I’m building a farm. My problem is that sometimes when I go to plant one the ground refuses to take my seed.

This is unacceptable! Resources are short. Sometimes walking a large distance away changes this though.

So I’m wondering is this an in-game mechanic I am unaware of or is this a bug? The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Crop_farming) has no mention of this as an in-game mechanic. I am using Java version 1.14.2.

Here is a screenshot of one of the affected areas:

[image]

I have tried removing the block, re-hoeing, and attempting to sow the seed again. Nothing worked. I even tried the soil in different states (wet or dry).

Comment: To those coming from HNQ: We all know the joke you want to make, it's already been made and deleted, since the comment section was getting crowded.

Comment: It is difficult to beat the titles from Arqade for double meanings.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Seeds are afraid of the dark, they don´t like the dark and cold farmland when the light level of the block they are in is under 8. They will want to stay with you, so you can keep them warm and protected.

Seeds are so afraid of the dark that they may ["pop off"](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat_Seeds#Crop) the ground in an attempt to find a player who can take care of them.

Give them a night light if you want your seeds to feel safe in a cave:

[image: A renamed torch in minecraft]

Comment: I thought this was a joke but decided to put a light down and all my crops exploded. When was this mechanic introduced? Or am I only noticing this now because I've never grown them in a cave before? +1 For the best answer I've ever been given btw.

Comment: @Reflexive The feature seems to have been introduced in 1.13, but I don´t know the exact snapshot. It is present in 1.13, but not in 1.12.2.

Comment: @Reflexive I am not quite sure how walking far away can fix this though, if nothing changes with the light, then walking far away should not solve your issue.

Comment: Perhaps i only thought that that was a solution. I could have perhaps put a torch down and not thought twice about it. I can't remember tbh.

Comment: To add to this awesome answer: Crops won't grow at night unless lighted up. This has been a feature since day one, but crops popping off is from a recent update. +1!

Comment: @Mr.Bear I think it is earlier than 1.13. I've seen people build villager farms around this lighting concept. Run a hopper minecart under the garden and shut off the lights. Turn back the lights on and the villager would replant everything.

Comment: @Mindwin You are correct, the "popping off" seems to be in 1.12.2. However it is possible to plant a seed even at a low light level in 1.12.2, which was what I tested and then I assumed that the "popping off" wasn´t implemented either. The seeds will pop off after a block update in 1.12.2, if the light level is too low.